# How to enable PKCE for Google login using spring-security-oauth2-client?

Tags: spring-security

The OAuth2 flow with Google login works for me, and I want to enable PKCE.

I configure the Google login in `application.yml`:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-id=<your client id>
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-secret=<your client secret>
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.provider=google
```

and

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .oauth2Login();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

I use `spring-security-oauth2-client` and my application uses Spring Boot.

**Reason why PKCE is not working for me:**

The PKCE flow is working until access the token endpoint to exchange the token with code verifier.

When registrering a client with configuring `clientAuthenticationMethod` as `none` and set empty client sercet, the client will use PKCE.

But Google's token endpoint requires `client secret` to access, so I have to configure client secret and cannot leave it as empty.

Is there other way to configure the OAuth2 flow with PKCE enabled in `application.yml` and follow the structure
`spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.xxx`?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer quickly.

Just add

```
    @Bean
    fun pkceResolver(repo: ClientRegistrationRepository): OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver {
        val resolver = DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver(repo,
            OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.DEFAULT_AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_BASE_URI
        )
        resolver.setAuthorizationRequestCustomizer(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestCustomizers.withPkce())
        return resolver
    }
```

and configure as

```
            http
            .oauth2Login()
            .authorizationEndpoint()
            .authorizationRequestResolver(pkceResolver)
```

I can find the code challenge is added to the request params.